# how to create Phonegap cancel button in phonegap .exec alert box?

Tags: cordova, cancel-button

How to create the cancel and ok button in phonegap using `PhoneGap.exec(null, null, "Notification", "activityStart", ["Downloading file","Please wait..."]);`

Answer (score 1):

```
 navigator.notification.confirm(
        'Do you want to signout and close the application?',  // message
        onConfirm,              // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
        'Sign Out',            // title
        'Sign Out,Cancel'          // buttonLabels
        );
```

and

```
function onConfirm(button) {
    //action for confirmation
}
```

Ref 
 http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_notification_notification.md.html

Answer (score 0):

Please specify in for whch tech you want to apply phonegap plugin (ios ,android)
below is the code which will help you create android core alertbox
call this function on execute method

```
 public synchronized void customalertBox(final String callBackId, JSONArray jarray) {
            final AlertDialog showCustomDialog = null;
            final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    AlertDialog.Builder customdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(null);
                    showCustomDialog.setButton2("OK", new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            customalertPLUGIN.success(new PluginResult(
                                    PluginResult.Status.OK, setJSONDataTORETURN),
                                    callBackId);
                            showCustomDialog.dismiss();

                        }
                    });
                    showCustomDialog.setButton2("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            customalertPLUGIN
                                    .error(new PluginResult(
                                            PluginResult.Status.INVALID_ACTION),
                                            callBackId);
                            showCustomDialog.dismiss();

                        }
                    });
                    showCustomDialog = customdialog.create();
                    showCustomDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    showCustomDialog.show();

                }

            };
        }
```

hope ths will help you.leave comment